# Django admin fieldset exclude or header field

Tags: django, header, admin, fieldset

I'm trying to create a new admin view that:
1. has a header of some kind
2. excludes 3 of my fields

Fieldset gives me the header I want, but doesn't seem to support "exclude", and I have not been able to find a "header" field.

Is there:
1. a header field that I don't know about
2. a way to exclude fields within Fieldset?

Comment: Huh? `fieldset` doesn't need an `exclude`. It only shows the fields you specify. If you don't want something to show, just don't add it to the list of fields.

Comment: The idea was that it would be much more efficient to just list the fields I wanted to exclude, since I have about 18 out of 20 fields I wanted to display.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. Unfortunately, no, there's no way to use both fieldsets and exclude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't exclude things the way you want to, unfortunately. You'll have to verbosely list every field that you want to include, like this:

```
fieldsets = (
    ('Basic Information', {
        'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'address', )
    }),
)
```

And so on!